Users cant edit own personal info in AD
I faced such a problem that users cannot fill in the office and description fields in AD. Previously, a script worked to add the computer's name to the user when logging into the session. It stopped working a few months ago, only now I've got my hands on it.
I tried to create test users in the same OU, copy ACLs from AD from problematic to new, copy group membership.
New users write without problems, and the old ones seem to have a field available for writing, but nothing can be entered there. At the same time, the field is not gray, as it usually happens when there is no access specifically.
The resulting rights to these attributes for the user show that there is access. But i can put info in this fields only as domain admin. From the user, the field itself looks the same, you can even put the cursor, but the text is not entered
I have not compared only the GPO, but I am not sure that this can be influenced by politicians. Moreover, the groups were copied to the test user and he is physically in the same container.
If you try to change it through the script, the Access Denied message appears
Exception calling "SetInfo" with "0" argument(s): "Access is denied.

Maybe someone has encountered something similar. I've already broken my head, I don't know what else to watch

Restore defaults + disable/enable inherited permissions fixes it, but i cant figure out which permissions was broken
